# How can I merge rear and front audio outputs in one?

Tags: sound, headphones, output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I hear only a few audio channels when playing video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163843/why-can-i-hear-only-a-few-audio-channels-when-playing-video-files)

I have Ubuntu 11.10 amd64

When I plug headphones into the front audio output - rear output stops working.

I had same problem on Win7, but it's easy solved by merging rear and front output in one in Realtek driver settings. How can I do it in Ubuntu 11.10 ?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Comment: I think this can help: http://askubuntu.com/a/231941/65926