# Why can I hear only a few audio channels when playing video files?

Tags: sound, multimedia, mkv

When I play specific MKV files there is not all the sound. There is actually only the background sound, like a song on the background, but I hear no talking.

The strangest thing is that it is not for all MKV files but for some. I can however not see a difference between the different files.

Comment: Which player are you using , try VLC.

Comment: This is happenning probably because you have stereo speakers but that mkv has more than 2 audio channels and the "talking channel" isn't being down muxed to stereo. Go to System Setting/Sound and try to find any configuration related to output mode and change it to Stereo Speakers.

Comment: @Eric Carvalho cool, it helped me too. You should give your answer for upvote.

Comment: @bioShark answer posted.

Answer (score 6):

This is happenning because you have stereo speakers but that MKV has more than 2 audio channels and the "talking channel" isn't being down muxed to stereo. Go to System Setting/Sound and try to find any configuration related to output mode and change it to Stereo Speakers.

Comment: Great tip. For me it happened when I plugged my head-phones into my 5.1 sound system. I notice the issue only when I was watching a mkv movie. It's logical when you think about it.

Comment: Solid answer. This only happened to me when watching an MKV movie that only had 5.1 and no other audio tracks

Comment: I had this issue on Windows when I tried playing MKV video on 5.1 channel , this tip helped me find the issue.Adding it here as it might help others. You can solve it by disabling all enhancements from sound settings in control panel.